# Laravel select random id from table

Tags: php, laravel

i want to select random id from inserted data into table by this code, this code work fine when i dont have deleted row(s) from table, how can i manage or skip deleted row(s) on this part of code:

```
rand($minId, $maxId)
```

code:

```
$minId = DB::table('channel_image_container')->min('id');
$maxId = DB::table('channel_image_container')->max('id');

while (!$c = DB::table('channel_image_container')->find(rand($minId, $maxId))) {
}

echo json_encode([
    'path' => 'images/' . $c->file_name,
    'content' => $c,
    'parent' => DB::table('channel_content_type')->where('id', $c->content_id)->first()
]);
```

this part of code is best solution?

```
while (!$c = DB::table('channel_image_container')->find(rand($minId, $maxId))) {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take advantage of `inRandomOrder()` **(Laravel >= 5.2)**:

```
$c = DB::table('channel_image_container')->inRandomOrder()->first();

echo json_encode([
    'path' => 'images/' . $c->file_name,
    'content' => $c,
    'parent' => DB::table('channel_content_type')->where('id', $c->content_id)->first()
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to take it like so:

```
$c = DB::table('channel_image_container')->take(1)->inRandomOrder()->get();

echo json_encode([
    'path' => 'images/' . $c->file_name,
    'content' => $c,
    'parent' => DB::table('channel_content_type')->whereId($c->content_id)->first()
]);
```

Comment: `take(1)` and `first()` mostly do the same thing(in this context). I dunno why this guy is getting downvoted.

Comment: IDK also, but i can say that this method is better at loading time due to the get function, at least by 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Because this is incorrect, his logic works with a single item and you are retrieving a collection. To access whatever propertie will fail with this method. As you can check here https://imgur.com/a/goArL